# EnsureLocalDisposalRule for XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, using-statement, gendarme

When I run Gendarme 2.11 on my C#.NET project the following code triggers the EnsureLocalDisposalRule:

```
XmlDocument myXmlDoc = this.GetXmlDoc();
foreach (XmlNode myNode in myXmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("TAGNAME"))
{
    ... does something with myNode ...
}
```

with the message:

> Local of type 'XmlNodeList' is not disposed of (at least not locally).

After reading the [rule description](https://github.com/spouliot/gendarme/wiki/Gendarme.Rules.Correctness.EnsureLocalDisposalRule(2.10)) 
I attempted to rewrite it as follows:

```
XmlDocument myXmlDoc = this.GetXmlDoc();
using (XmlNodeList myNodeList = myXmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("TAGNAME"))
{
    foreach (XmlNode myNode in myNodeList )
    {
        ... does something with myNode ...
    }
}
```

but this gives the error:

> 'System.Xml.XmlNodeList': type used in a using statement must be
>   implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

What is causing this? Is this a bug in Gendarme? Or have I misunderstood the rule? How could my code be improved?